# VB.NET SQL UPDATE command returns error "Argument not specified for parameter."

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset, ms-access-2007, sql-update

My update query (built from the dataset wizard) does not update anything and I am not receiving any errors.

I have checked my parameter (param1) and it is passing correctly.

When I debug my immediate window updateta.insertquery() tells me this:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'StockNum' of 'Public Overridable Function UpdateQuery(StockNum As String, Year As String, Make As String, Model As String, Color As String, Location As String, TiresNeeded As Boolean, StockIn As Date?, SvcRONum As String, UCIStartDate As Date?, UCIEstCompleteDate As Date?, Repairs As Boolean, CollisionRONum As String, Detail As Date?, Other As String, OnLot As Boolean, OffProperty As Boolean, Sold As Boolean, Original_RecNum As Integer) As Integer'.

why are there question marks after some of the dates??

here is my code vb code.  Any ideas??  Thanks!!

```
    Protected Sub SubmitBTN_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles UpdateBTN.Click
        Dim updateta As New DataSet1TableAdapters.MasterTableAdapter
        updateta.UpdateQuery(StockNumTxt.Text, YearTxt.Text, MakeTxt.Text, ModelTxt.Text, ColorTxt.Text, LocationDropDownList.SelectedValue, TiresCHK.Checked, StockInDateTxt.Text, SrvcROnumTxt.Text, UCIStartDateTxt.Text, UCIEstComDateTXT.Text, RepairsCheckBX.Checked, CollisionRONumTXT.Text, DetailTXTbox.Text, OtherTxt.Text, OnLotCheckBX.Checked, OffPropertyCheckBX.Checked, SoldCheckBX.Checked, Request.QueryString("param1"))
        Response.Redirect("success.aspx")
    End Sub

    Function myCStr(ByVal test As Object) As String
        If isdbnull(test) Then
            Return ("")
        Else
            Return CStr(test)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Function IsDBNull( _
 ByVal value As Object _
) As Boolean
        Return DBNull.Value.Equals(value)
    End Function

    Private Sub getData(ByVal user As String)
        'declare variables to fill
        Dim stock As String, make As String, color As String, stockin As Date, ucistart As Date, repairs As Boolean, _
            tires As Boolean, onlot As Boolean, sold As Boolean, year As Boolean, model As String, location As String, srvcRO As String, ucicompldate As Date, _
            collRO As String, other As String, offprop As Boolean, detail As Date

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\UsedCarProductionSched\UsedCars.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        connection.Open()
        Dim sqlcmd As String = "SELECT * from Master WHERE RecNum = @recnum"
        Dim FileCommand3 As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlcmd, connection)
        FileCommand3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@recnum", user)
        Dim Reader3 As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = FileCommand3.ExecuteReader()
        If Reader3.Read Then

            stock = myCStr(Reader3("StockNum"))
            make = myCStr(Reader3("Make"))
            color = myCStr(Reader3("Color"))
            stockin = IIf(Reader3("stockin") Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, Reader3("stockin"))
            ucistart = IIf(Reader3("ucistartdate") Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, Reader3("ucistartdate"))
            repairs = Reader3("Repairs")
            tires = Reader3("tiresneeded")
            onlot = Reader3("onlot")
            sold = Reader3("sold")
            year = myCStr(Reader3("year"))
            model = myCStr(Reader3("model"))
            location = myCStr(Reader3("location"))
            srvcRO = myCStr(Reader3("svcROnum"))
            ucicompldate = IIf(Reader3("uciestcompletedate") Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, Reader3("uciestcompletedate"))
            collRO = myCStr(Reader3("collisionROnum"))
            other = myCStr(Reader3("other"))
            offprop = Reader3("offProperty")
            detail = IIf(Reader3("detail") Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, Reader3("detail"))

        End If
        connection.Close()

        If detail <> Nothing Then
            DetailTXTbox.Text = detail.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")
        Else : DetailTXTbox.Text = ""
        End If
        If ucicompldate <> Nothing Then
            UCIEstComDateTXT.Text = ucicompldate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Else : UCIEstComDateTXT.Text = ""
        End If

        If stockin <> Nothing Then
            StockInDateTxt.Text = stockin.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Else : StockInDateTxt.Text = ""
        End If
        If ucistart <> Nothing Then
            UCIStartDateTxt.Text = ucistart.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")
        Else : UCIStartDateTxt.Text = ""
        End If
        StockNumTxt.Text = stock
        MakeTxt.Text = make
        ColorTxt.Text = color
        RepairsCheckBX.Checked = repairs
        TiresCHK.Checked = tires
        OnLotCheckBX.Checked = onlot
        SoldCheckBX.Checked = sold
        YearTxt.Text = year
        ModelTxt.Text = model
        If location <> Nothing Then
            LocationDropDownList.SelectedValue = location
        End If
        SrvcROnumTxt.Text = srvcRO
        CollisionRONumTXT.Text = collRO
        OtherTxt.Text = other
        OffPropertyCheckBX.Checked = offprop
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        getData(Request.QueryString("param1"))
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the question marks after Date?, I'm pretty sure that indicates the Date is a nullable field. Does your database table allow NULL on those fields?

When you put a debug break point right before your updateta.UpdateQuery, are you certain StockNumTxt.Text has a value?

Comment: yes..I have every field set to accept nulls except the identity.  
Also part of the reason im confused is my param is for "recnum" field not stocknum, so it shouldn't even matter if stocknum is empty (which its not)

Answer (score 0):

Access like `#` signs around dates. Have you tried putting `#` signs around your date values?